# xsd for optional XML tag with unknown subtags

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml

```
<File>
  <FileName>somefile.lis</FileName>
  <Metadata>
    <HeaderExtension expNum ="0">
      <ABC>DUMMY</ABC>
      <DEF>JUNK</DEF>
    </HeaderExtension>
    <HeaderExtension expNum ="1">
      <ABC>DUMMY</ABC>
      <GHI>Different JUNK</GHI>
    </HeaderExtension>
  </Metadata>
<File>
```

The Metadata tag is optional.  The HeaderExtension tag is optional under the Metadata tag and the all the subtags under either Metadata or HeaderExtension are unknown.  In my xsd I have the following defined

```
<xsd:complexType name="MetadataType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="FileInfo">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="FileName" type="xsd:string"
      minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="Metadata" type="MetadataType"
      minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xsd:sequence>
```

But for some reason this gives an error.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MetadataType'. No child element is expected at this point.

How do I change the xsd so that it validates the xml.

Comment: There is no element 'MetadataType' in your schema. How is your `File` element + complexType defined? Can you show more of your schema?

Comment: The error was wrong.  The error was:element Metadata: Schemas validity error : Element 'Metadata': This element is not expected.

Comment: You need to add more information. The XML headers, the namespaces, the definition of the `File` element which contains the `Metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MetadataType'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

doesn't seem to be caused by your schema. It's not related with the content in `Metadata` which is `any` and `lax`. It's probably an error in your *source* XML. This error would occur if you had something like this:

```
<File xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <FileName>somefile.lis</FileName>
    <Metadata>
        ...
    </Metadata>
    <MetadataType>...</MetadataType> <!-- unexpected element MetadataType -->
</File>
```

(I'm assuming that the complex type of File - which you didn't include in your question - is strict and doesn't accept elements called `MetadataType`.)

So probably a `<Metadata>` tag was generated with the name of its complex type instead of the name of the element.

Comment: I wrote the wrong error.  This is the error that came from the user  I ran the xsd thru "prettyprint", it looks like this, I have not changed the schema, I changed the xml doc from "Metadata" to "MetadataType" because of what I saw in the schema. Both cause the same error when the xml doc is parsed:
"Invalid content was found starting with element 'MetadataType'. No child element is expected at this point" or
"Invalid content was found starting with element 'Metadata'. No child element is expected at this point"